# Is the session in CodeIgniter safe?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Just need some advice about using the session in Codeigniter.
I have a question. My question is if I use this code:

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

I understand that it will unset all the session data. But what if I am running 2 different computers and connected in 1 database. If I clear the session data in my first computer does it affect the session data in my 2nd computer?

I have a logout page. And I am just wondering if I logout the the account in my first PC. Does it affect in the 2nd PC? Meaning if I am running my code in multiple PC. If I unset all the data in my session by using this code **$this->session->sess_destroy();** Will it destroy the other sessions?

That's all guys thanks.

Comment: If you remove session data from your pc it does not affect 2nd pc.

Comment: if you are on a same PC and accessing your website or anything through two different browser it will not affect each other